# How to get DOM element from touch event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the code to add the class in onclick is 100% worked on desktop browser but doesn't work on mobile android webview. The alert on mobile is not shown.

```
<button onclick="alert('test');this.classList.toggle('newclass');" >
```

I found how to run  onclick on android webview like below.  The alert is shown but toggle function doesn't work.

```
newNode.addEventListener("touchstart",function (e){
    alert("test");
    e.classList.toggle('newclass');
}, false)
```

but want to add the class of current node touched is not working. The It's said:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (app_mobile.js:5799)

Actually how to get dom element and add/change class of it's element using touch event for android webviee?

Comment: `e` is a [`TouchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) not an `HTMLElement`. Read the docs on how to get the touched element.

Comment: I'd avoid using any inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.classList.toggle` should be `e.target.classList.toggle`.

`e` is event that is passed to your callback. If you want to deal with the HTML element which triggered this event, you use `e.target` to get to it